# Extract and Convert string to string in R

Tags: r, string, string-concatenation, stringr

In a data frame, I want to extract from a string just the numbers inside the string.  I already did this fine.

Now I want to concatenate or str_c those vector inside every row into single strings.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
txt <- c("A 9 out of 10", "no numbers", "just 1 number", "2 numbers 33")
right <- c("9 10", "NULL", "1", "2 33")

df <- data.frame(id, txt, right)

df <- df %>% mutate(
Numbers_Title = str_extract_all(txt, "\\b[0-9]+\\b"))
```

So far, so good, now I need to convert the multiple strings in every row into just 1 string per row. This is the part that is not working for me

```
df1 <- df %>% mutate(
Numbers_String = str_c(Numbers_Title))

df1 <- df %>% unlist(Numbers_Title)
```

Thanks!

This was flagged as a Duplicate, but it wasn't at all.

Thanks, but is not a duplicate. In the other case they wanted to keep the string separated and make a tidier data frame. In my case I want to make every vector of strings inside a cell in a data frame into just one string.

Based on akrun answer, I was able to solve it.

Here is how I did it

```
df1 <- df %>% rowwise %>% mutate(
Numbers_String = toString(Numbers_Title))
```

Thanks again

Comment: You might need `sapply(str_extract_all(df$txt, '\\d+'), function(x) if(length(x)>0) toString(x) else NA)`

Comment: @Jaap nice dupe find

Comment: Thanks, but is not a duplicate.  In the other case they wanted to keep the string separated and make a tidier data frame.  In my case I want to make every vector of strings inside a cell in a data frame into just one string.

Comment: Based on akrum solution, I was able to solve the issue with a small change